# Reutilizar a função no javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Pessoal estou com a seguinte duvida,queria manipular um valor especifico na minha função,aonde o valor atribuído não seja fixo e sim dinâmico(aonde eu posso alterar com forme a necessidade).

```
function mostrardiv() 
  {
      document.getElementById("teste").style.display = "block"; 
  }
```

No document.getElementById o id que ele recebe é teste porem eu queria ter a liberdade de que ao chamar a função no codigo eu podesse mudar o valor que é atribuído ao document.getElementById.

Eu procurei sobre o assunto,só achei como usar o prototype no javascript,porem ainda não entendi como eu posso trocar o valor atribuído no document.getElementByI.

A forma como eu pensei seira mais o menos assim:

```
function mostrardiv(val) 
  {
      document.getElementById(this.val).style.display = "block";
  }
```

Mas não deu certo no html eu usei a função assim:

```
 <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-md-2" onmouseover="mostrardiv('teste')" > <img class="img-responsive" src="_imagens/1.png" >
 </div>
```

Comment: Simples crie um id na sua div ex: `id="minhaDiv"` altere o parametro para ex: `mostrardiv(this)`  va na  função e mude para `val.id`

Comment: Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/sqosv654/

Comment: Outra coisa, como você esta usando bootstrap poderia ja utilizar jQuery né?

Comment: Sim ,mas ainda não estou confiante com o javascript ahahhahah,uma pergunta ele só minha função tiver declarado no mesmo  lugar que estar o id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria mais ou menos igual está abaixo, porem o `onmouseover="mostrardiv(this)"` teria que estar dentro da tag do elemento que você quer pegar o ID.

```
<div class="col-md-2" onmouseover="mostrardiv(this)" > 
    <img class="img-responsive" src="_imagens/1.png" > 
</div>

function mostrardiv(campo) 
{
  document.getElementById(campo.value).style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Comment: Você testou essa solução antes de responder? pelo que estou vendo, se você utiliza um seletor por id é esperado que o id esteja na tag e no seu exemplo não existe nenhum id.

Comment: teste mas como eu mostrei eu escrevi errado no codigo,muito obrigado funcionou como eu queria :)